# Semivariance calculation (downside deviation)

Tags: portfolio-management, risk, risk-management

what is the  accurate formula for semivariance? 
I see two versions up to now:

1. [this version](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/semivariance.asp) which considers as *N* (denominator) all the numbers over/under the mean-or any other number. This is the same of a version of CFA (book: Quantitative Methods for Investment Analysis - 2004 page 136). This is the formula:

[image]

2. Another version (stated in another CFA´s book) shows a different formula. This is the formula (taken for another source):

[image].

The first difference is in the numerator (which is Min between "a","b") and the second is in the denominator (where *N* is over the **entire** sample).

Which one is the correct one and why? I want to use this in the Sortino ratio

PD: In addition, I found this other comment which summarizes what I meant ([link](https://www.bionicturtle.com/forum/threads/shortcut-to-calculating-semi-variance-mean-squared-deviation.6418/)):

> ShaktiRathore It was my understanding that the downside deviation (i.e., denominator in Sortino) does not include the zeros; i.e., when PMAR, these positive excess values are EXCLUDED, not treated as zero. Although I had understood this to be the GIPS-compliant method (at the time I sat for the CIPM but this was several years ago ....), it seems to be controversial...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am interested in Semivariance because I want to use it to compute the Sortino Ratio. I found an article on Sortino which answers to my question. Here is [the link](http://www.sunrisecapital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Futures_Mag_Sortino_0213.pdf) "Sortino ratio: A better measure of risk, by Tom Rollinger and Scott Hoffman", Futures Magazine 2013.

In this article the Sortino Ratio is defined as
$$SR=\frac{R-T}{TDD}$$
where R is the average period return, T is the target or required rate of return, and TDD is the Target Downside Deviation, which is found as
$$TDD=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i-1}^N[\min(0,X_i-T)]^2}$$

From a practical point of view, the calculation must take into account all the data (substituting a zero for those values above or equal to your target), not just the observations below the target. This is so the Sortino ratio will return a higher value that Sharpe ratio when there are many observations above the target. If you consider a reduced sample (excluding zeros in the denominator) the Sortino will be lower than Sharpe, which is not the idea of this ratio.

> "The Sortino ratio takes into account both the frequency of
>   below-target returns as well as the magnitude of them. Throwing away
>   the zero underperformance data points removes the ratio’s sensitivity
>   to frequency of underperformance."

Example from the link:

> "Consider the following underperformance return streams:  `[0, 0, 0, –10]` and `[–10, –10, –10, –10]`. Throwing away the zero
>   underperformance data points results in the same target downside
>   deviation for both return streams, but clearly the first return stream
>   has much less downside risk than the second."

So, I should not discard any zero because I will be reducing the data, which results in a lower Sortino than Sharpe ratio.

Finally, I would like to point it out that I found papers and books (one was from the CFA) that compute semivariance using the first method (throwing away the zeros). So I think confusion around it is still there.

Comment: Could you put it in your own words? Link only answers tend to become unusable after some time.